# Civilization 5: Does Arts funding and Science funding cancel each other out?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

If both Arts funding and Science funding are active at the same time, is the result the same as if neither of them were active?

Comment: I'll test this out when I get home tonight, but math says no - assuming 10 GPPT and both active, 10 * .67 * 1.33 = 8.911. Assuming they're multiplicative, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bonuses and penalties in Civ are added, not multiplied. The +33% and -33% cancel each other out.